# Not able to boot Ubuntu 12.04 after installation in Windows 7 PC

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using USB drive. Only the UEFI port option is shown in the initial boot screen and not the Legacy boot. 
Once I select , install along with Windows it goes through smoothly and after restart of the machine, the Ubuntu option is not present. It boots only the existing Windows 7.

Not sure what is the reason. Could any one of please help on this? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Search for how to fix [Grub loader version 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2). You'll be needing min. 4GB pen drive and Ubuntu 12.04 and Unetbootin software.